# How to shift a row to column inside a `div` if the container is using `display : flex`

Tags: html, css

I have least knowledge about css. The question might be silly for you.I am facing a problem to shifting `div` using `display : flex`
Let me explain :

This is my template :

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar{
  background: grey;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}
.header{
  background: orange;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  
}
.content{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">sidenav</div>
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
  </div>
```

The result I am getting is `.content` is placed at the last of the same row. I want it below the `.header`
What I want :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange your div to match your requirement. Something like below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar {
  background: grey;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  background: orange;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">sidenav</div>

  <div class="container column">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vcdu0tjo/1/

Comment: Yeah exactly that's what I wanted. Thanks for your great support.